# How do Biblical Unitarians explain Daniel 7:13's use of the phrase 'like the son of man'?

Tags: christology, messiah, daniel

Daniel 7:13 is

> "In my vision in the night I continued to watch, and I saw One **like
> the Son of Man** coming with the clouds of heaven. He approached the
> Ancient of Days and was led into His presence."

(Alternate translation is "like a Son of Man")

This language suggests the Messiah wasn't a 'mere man', but rather something else.

How do Biblical Unitarians explain the language used in Daniel 7:13 as applied to Jesus?

Answer (score 2):

Jesus uses this same expression to refer to himself, in particular if he refers to his return when the Kingdom of God will be fulfilled.
Biblical Unitarians do not say that Jesus is a man like you and I. He is the appointed Messiah. But the Messiah is a human, not a half-god. The expression Son of Man underlines just that he is a human and that he has an outstanding role for us attrbuted to him by his and our Father, God.

Comment: You might also mention Daniel's use of the same expression in the next chapter [8:17](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=%22son+of+man%22&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_3), where Daniel himself is referred to as "*son of man*". And note that capitalization was supplied by the English translators.