# How do Biblical Unitarians reconcile Deuteronomy 33:26, where there is 'none like God' in the clouds, and Daniel 7:13, with the son of man in clouds?

Tags: daniel, unitarianism, deuteronomy, biblical-unitarian

Deuteronomy 33:26 is

> "There is none like the God of Jeshurun, who rides the heavens to your
> aid, and the clouds in His majesty."

Biblical Unitarians take Daniel 7:13 to be a Messianic prophecy, and it has

> "I saw One like the Son of Man coming with the clouds of heaven. He
> approached the Ancient of Days and was led into His presence."

If the Son of Man = God, then the fact the Son of Man in coming with the clouds of heaven is easy to reconcile with Deut. 33:26, where it seems to describe an exclusive activity of God - riding the clouds.

How do Biblical Unitarians, who believe the Son of Man is a divine figure in a sense, but not God, reconcile these two verses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Biblical Unitarians explain Daniel 7:13's use of the phrase 'like the son of man'?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91436/how-do-biblical-unitarians-explain-daniel-713s-use-of-the-phrase-like-the-son)

Comment: @Anne This is a distinct question. I'm not asking for an understanding of the term 'like a son of man' from a BU perspective, I'm asking how the riding on the clouds for someone who isn't = God can be squared with Deut. 33:26.

Comment: Does riding the clouds make one God? Could it be that the 'none like' portion speaks of His essence and not what He is doing? Then, others who do not share His essence may also ride on the clouds.